# Python 3.3 - Game - Hint System

Tags: python

I want to make it so it prints different hints dependent on where the player is in the game. I tried it by setting the value of 'Hint' every time the player went somewhere. Obviously I came across a flaw (as I'm here). The value of `Hint = 1` was first in one def and I couldn't manage to summon it when writing the Help/Hint def. My pathetic example:

```
def Room_Choice():
    Hint = 1
```

(60 lines down)

```
def Hint():
    Choice = input("What would you like?\n")
    if Choice == ("Hint"):
        if Room_Choice(Hint = 1):
            print_normal("blah blah blah\n")
        else:
            print_normal("HINT-ERROR!\n")
            Help_Short()
```

And obviously as the game developed more and more values of hint would be added.
As you can see I'm relatively new to Python and need help.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to reach a value that exists in a **function scope**, and you're doing it wrong (as you're here).

Imagine scopes as boxes of one-way mirrors : when you're inside one, you can see what's in the box and what's outside of the box. But **you can't see what's in a box you are not in**.

Here, **Hint** exists within the box of **Room_Choice**, but not in the box of H... oh wait.

You've called your function Hint too ! If you want to reach Hint in a function called Hint with no Hint defined inside the function, you'll probably get the function. Let's call the function **DoHint**()

So you can't see Hint from within DoHint, because it's in another box. You have to put it somewhere *(over the rainboooow... sorry for that)* you can see it.
You might want to put it at the **module level** (not within a def), or make it an **object's attribute** (but you'll have to know bits of Oriented Object Programming to understand that).

This is really basic programming skills, I can't really explain further without knowing what you're trying to do and showing you how I would do it, but I hope that helped.

Just one more thing on this line : `if Room_Choice(Hint = 1):`, here you're trying to check if the result of the Room_Choice function with a value of 1 for the Hint parameter is True. I don't know what you wanted to do, but the Room_Choice function doesn't show it can handle any parameters (you should get an error on that), and will not return a boolean value (it will implicitly return None, which is evaluated as a logical False).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can't express how stupid I do feel . . .